# Determine the principal argument of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Given a non-zero complex number $z$, we define $Arg(z)=\theta$ if and only if $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$, $r>0$.

For a real number $0<x<1$ and a positive integer $m$, my goal is to determine
$$
Arg\big[\sin((m+1)x\pi) e^{-mx\pi i}\big]\qquad(\ast)
$$

**My attempt**:

If $\frac{2k}{m+1}<x<\frac{2k+1}{m+1}$, then $\sin((m+1)x\pi)>0$, so $(\ast)=Arg\big[e^{-mx\pi i}\big]$.

If $\frac{2k+1}{m+1}<x<\frac{2k+2}{m+1}$, then $\sin((m+1)x\pi)<0$, so $(\ast)=Arg\big[-e^{-mx\pi i}\big]$.

How to determine $Arg\big[\pm e^{-mx\pi i}\big]$ acording to the above intervals ?

Answer (score 1):

First write $$-mx\pi=2\pi n+r$$ such that we have $r\in[0,2\pi)$ and $n$ is an integer.

###### Case 1:

If $r\in [0,\pi)$ then $arg(e^{-mx\pi i})=r$.

###### Case 2:

If $r\in (\pi,2\pi)$ then $arg(e^{-mx\pi i})=\pi-r$.

You can similarly deal with $arg(e^{-mx\pi i})$ if you notice that $|arg(z)|+|arg(-z)|=\pi$, as is intuitively obvious from their representations on the Argand plane.